# Behaviour of a certain arithmetic function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, arithmetic-functions

Here, $\sigma(n)= \text{the sum of divisors of }n$.

For fun, I have been messing around on Mathematica with a particular arithmetical function, whose asymptotic behaviour I am interested in.

First, define $g(n)=\sigma(\sigma(n)) - \sigma(n)$. Next, define

$$s(n) = |\{ k:g(k)=n\}|.$$

Finally, our function:

$$S(n) = \sum_{1<i \leq n}s(i).$$

Now, some details are in order.

1. $s(1)$ is infinite; ie. $g(k)=1$ whenever $\sigma(k)$ is prime.
2. For $n>1$,  $s(n)$ is finite. In fact, it is often zero.

**I am interested in understanding the growth of** $S(n)$. For small $n$, it appears linear. Below is a graph for $n\leq1600$.

[image]

It is definitely not linear though. Since we are working with $\sigma$, we can expect any closed-form expressions for, say, asymptotics, to have some double $\log$ terms.

Unfortunately I am a busy undergraduate student who knows nothing about analytic number theory! I don't have much work of my own, but I thought this was interesting enough to share. **Is there a systematic approach to finding asymptotics for functions defined like $s,S$?**

If we instead defined $s(n)$ to be the number of solutions to $\sigma(k)=n$, the corresponding $S(n)$ grows at a faster (and smoother) rate.